# Can we disable windows update through services.msc

Tags: windows-10, automatic-update

Can we able to disable the Windows 10 automatic update by disabling the wuauserv in services.msc? And also please confirm whether disabling the wuauserv will affect the system?

Answer (score 1):

U can set the internet connection to **Metered Connection** to disable automatic updates.

Go to `Settings` , `Networking` and View Connection Properties, and set the active connection as **Metered**.

Comment: If we set the internet connection to Metered connection, the live tiles no longer update properly. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: No. Microsoft has enforced automatic updates on windows10. The real use case of turning off automatic updates is if on a limited data or low bandwidth connection. I think its better to ignore live tiles on such connections. I'm not on windows10 currently but i guess it should be possible to manually update live tiles on a click or something similar...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes you can, long answer is why would you want too?

You are better to tell Windows to notify but never download so you can at least have control over updating. Disabling this service it will do nothing at all with Windows Updates.

You also cannot download apps from the Windows Store with this disabled to my knowledge.

Comment: Windows 10 automatic update consuming 3/4 of my internet bandwidth.

Comment: In that case just set it to notify, you can then start them as and when you do not require the bandwidth (overnight for example) would that not help?

Comment: @CharlesH there isn't an option to `notify about updates but donot download them` in windows 10 home. They will be automatically downloaded.

Comment: If you click start menu and type gpedit then load the group policy editor. Go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Configure Automatic Updates > Enable this and set to Notify for Download and Notify for Install.... This should stop them downloading and notify you...

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution that doesn't rely on services.

> 1.Type in the search bar **gpedit.msc** and run it as Administrator.

2.Next, navigate to: *Computer configuration* > *Administrative Templates* > *Windows Components* > *Windows Update*

> 3.Right-click *Configure Automatic Updates* and select **Edit**

4.*Enable it* , then select **2 - Notify to download and notify to install**

It should look like this
[image]

> 5.Save everything and restart your computer.

This option allows you to manually download and install the updates almost like in older versions of Windows ( that's because you can't select which updates you want to install unfortunately ). Here are some screenshots:
[image]
 Main Menu

[image]
Advanced options

As you can see, this only works for **Windows 10 Pro** (see.- defer upgrades). Beware that update KB3081455 may disable this in gropu policy editor, so try to avoid it somehow just like a driver update (try use [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930) tool).

Comment: Sorry didn't see this before I added my comment below!

Comment: This does not work for Home editions or lower, there is no gpedit in these versions of Windows.

Comment: The problem is that the author didn't specified his version of Windows. If he has the Home version you are right. But if he does have the Pro version, this answer applies to him.